# How to upgrade cordova-plugin-ionic-webview from 1.2.1 to 5.0.0 without data loss

Tags: ionic3, local-storage, angularfire2, indexeddb, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview

By upgrading `cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 1.2.1` to `5.0.0` the `firebase` user gets logged out automatically on `android devices`. It worked properly on ios devices even after upgrading the webview to 5.0.0.

```
this.angularFireAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pswd);
```

**ionic 3** and **cordova-android 10.1.1**

I have to upgrade plugin due to AppStore Deprecation notice (Apple will stop accepting submissions of apps that use UIWebView APIs).

Any solutions if anyone had faced the relevant problem?

Answer (score 0):

use these commands:

```
cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-ionic-webview
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ionic-webview@latest
```

If you need a specific version, replace `latest` by the version you need.